# Generic Method Java without reflection

Tags: java, android, facebook, generics

I am using the Facebook graph API ,every request looks almost the same except the method name. 
as you see I have two requests here the only different thing is the method,
How do I make it generic,I want to create a method that gets the name of the method and applies it. 
Is there a way to do this without reflection ?or this is the right way to do it.

```
 GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                access_token,
                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(
                            JSONObject jsonObject,
                            GraphResponse response) {
                        // Application code for user
                    }
                }),
 GraphRequest.newMyFriendsRequest(
                access_token,
                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONArrayCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(
                            JSONArray jsonArray, 
                            GraphResponse response) {
                        // Application code for users friends 
                    }
                })
```

Comment: You can't make it generic without reflection.

Comment: ok thank you,I thought maybe there is a better solution to this.

Comment: What about lambda expressions? If you are using Android Studio and have JDK8 installed, you can use lambda expressions.